# method create multiple panels

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

How can I create multiple panels in a jframe with a method.
I want to give the method a number and then the method shall create this amount of Jpanels. Is there any way how I can do this automatically, because I have to create over 100 Panels

Comment: Just create an array, use a for-loop to populate it and return the array.

Comment: `I want to give the method a number and then the method shall create this amount of Jpanels` Use a loop

Comment: `public JPanel[] createPanels(int amount) {JPanel[] panels = new JPanel[amount];for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {panels[i] = new JPanel();}return panels;}`

Comment: I would recommend reading up on loops and control structure basics before getting into swing.

Comment: thanks @LukasRotter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually if you want to perform an action over an over again you would use a **loop**. In this case I think it would be best that you use a [for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

```
public void addJPanelsToJFrame(JFrame frame, int panels){
    for (int q = 0; q < panels; q++){
        frame.add(new JPanel());
    }
}
```